# What punctuation do I use between the words "words" and "he"?

Tags: grammar

Thousands of people gathered just to hear his motivating *words he* was truly an inspiration to others.

Comment: Those are two separate sentences.  The standard prescriptivist punctuation would be either a period or a semicolon.

Answer (score 2):

Stick a period right after "words." Capitalize "he."

Bonus: remove "just" from the resulting first sentence. It'll read cleaner.

> Thousands of people gathered to hear his motivating words. He was truly an inspiration to others.

And that is all I have to say about this matter.